# Haproxy Incoming X-Forwarded-For Header into Outgoing X-Forwarded-For

Tags: haproxy, x-forwarded-for

Is there any way that I can use Haproxy's ability to modify headers so that if the incoming connection has an X-Forwarded-For header for example I can then take the contents of this and add it into Haproxy's X-Forwarded-For record?

My Current Scenario is a client has setup the following:

- CloudFlare Takes Connection, sets X-Forwarded-For and connects to Haproxy frontend
- Haproxy then handles this connection and sets the X-Forwarded-For based on the true IP for the connection received (CloudFlares IP Address)
- Server receives this request and the X-Forwarded-For entry contains the IP of the CloudFlare proxy rather than the true Client IP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless your final server really wants to know what the cloudflare IP address was, if nobody connects directly to haproxy, then just remove `option forwardfor` so it stops changing the X-Forwarded-For header.

If some connections do not go through cloudflare, you can use `option forwardfor except cloudflareipaddress` to only set X-Forwarded-For for direct connections.